# Deserializing a response containing __c

Tags: apex

I can't seem to find a solution to the following problem.

I'm connecting to a web service through REST and the service replies with the following:

```
"attachment__c:" = "test"
```

However if I try to deserialize the response into an object for example:

```
myclass deserializeResponse = (myclass) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), myclass.class);

public class myclass(){
    String attachment__c { get; set; }
}
```

I won't be able to due to the `__c` being a reserved word.

Is there any workaround on how I can get the value from the response into an object?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `Map<String, Object>`.

```
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
```

Comment: This was causing a lot of issues as the response was returning a huge string and it was a lot of work to parse it.  Meanwhile Ive figured out a solution. I could directly deserialize the response and replace the __c field on the same line, like this: myclass deserializeResponse = (myclass) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody().replaceAll('attachment__c',attachmentId), myclass.class);